# Django celery worker __init__() error

Tags: django, celery, newrelic, mixpanel

The tech stack looks like this:

- Django frontend and backend
- Celery worker queue for asynchronously processing time consuming tasks

Within the past day or two I've noticed a lot of these kinds of stack traces both locally and in production:

```
[2012-07-05 20:31:01,583: CRITICAL/MainProcess] Task site_endpoint.tasks.async_inbound_message[a950736c-ff93-420c-9fbf-6deb2b88ff4d] INTERNAL ERROR: TypeError('__init__() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)',)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/projects/site/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/execute/trace.py", line 192, in trace_task
    R = I.handle_error_state(task, eager=eager)
  File "/projects/site/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/execute/trace.py", line 91, in handle_error_state
    }[self.state](task, store_errors=store_errors)
  File "/projects/site/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/execute/trace.py", line 114, in handle_failure
    task.backend.mark_as_failure(req.id, exc, self.strtb)
  File "/projects/site/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 96, in mark_as_failure
    traceback=traceback)
  File "/projects/site/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/celery/backends/base.py", line 229, in store_result
    return self._store_result(task_id, result, status, traceback, **kwargs)
  File "/projects/site/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/backends/database.py", line 26, in _store_result
    traceback=traceback)
  File "/projects/site/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/managers.py", line 40, in _inner
    return fun(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/projects/site/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/managers.py", line 164, in store_result
    "traceback": traceback})
  File "/projects/site/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/managers.py", line 82, in update_or_create
    return self.get_query_set().update_or_create(**kwargs)
  File "/projects/site/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/djcelery/managers.py", line 66, in update_or_create
    obj, created = self.get_or_create(**kwargs)
  File "/projects/site/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 385, in get_or_create
    obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
  File "/projects/site/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 460, in save
    self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
  File "/projects/site/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 543, in save_base
    for f in meta.local_fields if not isinstance(f, AutoField)]
  File "/projects/site/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/subclassing.py", line 28, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/projects/site/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/subclassing.py", line 28, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/projects/site/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 276, in get_db_prep_save
    return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)
  File "/projects/site/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/subclassing.py", line 53, in inner
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/projects/site/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/picklefield/fields.py", line 154, in get_db_prep_value
    value = force_unicode(dbsafe_encode(value, self.compress, self.protocol))
  File "/projects/site/venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/picklefield/fields.py", line 57, in dbsafe_encode
    value = b64encode(dumps(deepcopy(value), pickle_protocol))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 190, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 328, in _reconstruct
    args = deepcopy(args, memo)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 163, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 237, in _deepcopy_tuple
    y.append(deepcopy(a, memo))
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 190, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, rv, 1, memo)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/copy.py", line 329, in _reconstruct
    y = callable(*args)
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)
```

Looking at the database calls when this happens, I can see the following queries being executed:

```
LOG:  statement: SELECT "celery_taskmeta"."id", "celery_taskmeta"."task_id", "celery_taskmeta"."status", "celery_taskmeta"."result", "celery_taskmeta"."date_done", "celery_taskmeta"."traceback" FROM "celery_taskmeta" WHERE "celery_taskmeta"."task_id" = 'a950736c-ff93-420c-9fbf-6deb2b88ff4d' 
LOG:  statement: SAVEPOINT s140735259576672_x4
LOG:  statement: ROLLBACK
LOG:  statement: BEGIN
LOG:  statement: SELECT "celery_taskmeta"."id", "celery_taskmeta"."task_id", "celery_taskmeta"."status", "celery_taskmeta"."result", "celery_taskmeta"."date_done", "celery_taskmeta"."traceback" FROM "celery_taskmeta" WHERE "celery_taskmeta"."task_id" = 'a950736c-ff93-420c-9fbf-6deb2b88ff4d' 
LOG:  statement: SAVEPOINT s140735259576672_x5
LOG:  statement: ROLLBACK
LOG:  statement: BEGIN
LOG:  statement: SELECT "celery_taskmeta"."id", "celery_taskmeta"."task_id", "celery_taskmeta"."status", "celery_taskmeta"."result", "celery_taskmeta"."date_done", "celery_taskmeta"."traceback" FROM "celery_taskmeta" WHERE "celery_taskmeta"."task_id" = 'a950736c-ff93-420c-9fbf-6deb2b88ff4d' 
LOG:  statement: SAVEPOINT s140735259576672_x6
```

I am having a tough time understanding what the source of this invalid object initialization is.  Anyone have ideas?

Comment: If you are experiencing this problem in any Celery installation, take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314189/python-multiprocessing-pool-hangs-at-join

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using new-relic remote performance monitoring/forensic analysis.  I have seen this kind of problem before when old versions of the library are being used.  I recommend checking to make sure you are using the latest version of their client library.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me and I solved it by reading [Python multiprocessing pool hangs at join?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314189/python-multiprocessing-pool-hangs-at-join) and http://bugs.python.org/issue9400.

### The problem:

Celery somehow pickles the exceptions it gets and sends them somewhere (to the database/broker, I guess). So, if, at any time, a Celery task raises an exception that isn't pickleable, this bug will happen.

### The solution:

You must ensure you're handling all the bizarre exceptions your Celery tasks code might be raising. The `Traceback` can give you hints, but it may not be very exact about everything.

If you really don't know where are your exceptions coming from, try putting your tasks code inside `try...except: pass` blocks.