# Python multiprocessing pool hangs at join?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm trying to run some python code on several files in parallel.  The construct is basically:

```
def process_file(filename, foo, bar, baz=biz):
    # do stuff that may fail and cause exception

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # setup code setting parameters foo, bar, and biz

    psize = multiprocessing.cpu_count()*2
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=psize)

    map(lambda x: pool.apply_async(process_file, (x, foo, bar), dict(baz=biz)), sys.argv[1:])
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

I've previously used pool.map to do something similar and it worked great, but I can't seem to use that here because pool.map doesn't (appear to) allow me to pass in extra arguments (and using lambda to do it won't work because lambda can't be marshalled).

So now I'm trying to get things to work using apply_async() directly.  My issue is that the code seems to hang and never exit.  A few of the files fail with an exception, but i don't see why what would cause join to fail/hang? Interestingly if none of the files fail with an exception, it does exit cleanly.

What am I missing?

Edit: When the function (and thus a worker) fails, I see this exception:

```
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 552, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 505, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 376, in _handle_results
    task = get()
TypeError: ('__init__() takes at least 3 arguments (1 given)', <class 'subprocess.CalledProcessError'>, ())
```

If i see even one of these, the process parent process hangs forever, never reaping the children and exiting.

Comment: Your code seems to work just fine, even if I throw random exceptions in `process_file`. So perhaps it has to do with what you're actually doing in `process_file` that's causing the problems.

Comment: Huh. what version of python? I'm on 2.7.  process_file in the real program is quite complex, making heavy use of PIL, NetworkX, poly2tri, and other libraries.  I know of at least 2 places I have known bugs that can cause exceptions in some cases, but I need to simply ignore those errors and move on. I'm stumped as to why it would never exit for me but work for you.

Comment: 2.7.2, this is what I tested with: https://gist.github.com/robertklep/5125319

Comment: That certainly looks like a reasonable test case, and it runs fine on my system too.  Now I'm completely lost.

Comment: Are you starting subprocesses from within your workers?

Comment: yes. is that a problem?

Comment: I also just saw this: http://bugs.python.org/issue9400

Comment: Right, that looks very similar.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Sorry to answer my own question, but I've found at least a workaround so in case anyone else has a similar issue I want to post it here.  I'll accept any better answers out there.

I believe the root of the issue is http://bugs.python.org/issue9400 . This tells me two things:

- I'm not crazy, what I'm trying to do really is supposed to work
- At least in python2, it is very difficult if not impossible to pickle 'exceptions' back to the parent process.  Simple ones work, but many others don't.

In my case, my worker function was launching a subprocess that was segfaulting. This returned CalledProcessError exception, which is not pickleable.  For some reason, this makes the pool object in the parent go out to lunch and not return from the call to join().

In my particular case, I don't care what the exception was.  At most I want to log it and keep going. To do this, I simply wrap my top worker function in a try/except clause.  If the worker throws any exception, it is caught before trying to return to the parent process, logged, and then the worker process exits normally since it's no longer trying to send the exception through.  See below:

```
def process_file_wrapped(filenamen, foo, bar, baz=biz):
    try:
        process_file(filename, foo, bar, baz=biz)
    except:
        print('%s: %s' % (filename, traceback.format_exc()))
```

Then, I have my initial map function call process_file_wrapped() instead of the original one.  Now my code works as intended.

Comment: You don't need to apologize for answering your own question. This page now documents a real problem with a workaround. That's good.

Comment: By the way, another solution might be to take just the exception's error message and raise out using the base "Exception" class, which I assume is pickleable.

Comment: I'm still new to StackExchange, and I'm unsure about etiquette.  Given @robertklep 's snippet from the comments above works with a plain Exception(), I suspect that would be fine too.. but the bottom line is that you must catch any exceptions and return a known-to-work one.

Comment: I am feeling lucky to find this post. [That python bug](http://bugs.python.org/issue9400) still has a status "Open" at this time, 2014.

Answer (score 5):

You can actually use a `functools.partial` instance instead of a `lambda` in cases where the object needs to be pickled. `partial` objects are pickleable since Python 2.7 (and in Python 3).

```
pool.map(functools.partial(process_file, x, foo, bar, baz=biz), sys.argv[1:])
```

Comment: Hmm. I haven't used functools before.  Thanks for the info. I still suspect this will still suffer the same exception-propogation problem though.

Comment: Possibly; I can't tell. You did mention that you had prior success with `pool.map`, so maybe this will help.

Comment: I used pool.map in a completely different context, where things weren't likely to cause exceptions. I should have been clearer about that in the question.

Comment: `functools.partial()` will allow you to use `Pool.map()` in more scenarios, but it doesn't affect the exception problem. I just ran into the same problem with `CalledProcessError` hanging the pool. Catching, logging, and raising a `RuntimeError` worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

For what it's worth, I had a similar bug (not the same) when `pool.map` hung. **My** use case allowed me to use [pool.terminate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.terminate) to solve it (make sure yours does as well before changing stuff).

I used [pool.map](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map) before calling `terminate` so I know everything finished, from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.map):

> A parallel equivalent of the map() built-in function (it supports only one iterable argument though). It blocks until the result is ready.

If that's your use case this may be a way to patch it.