# Python multi processing . Handle exception in parent process and make all children die gracefully

Tags: python, python-decorators, python-multiprocessing

I have this following code.

This uses a python module called decorator .

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from random import randint
import traceback
import decorator
import time


def test_retry(number_of_retry_attempts=1, **kwargs):
    timeout = kwargs.get('timeout', 2.0) # seconds
    @decorator.decorator
    def tryIt(func, *fargs, **fkwargs):
        for _ in xrange(number_of_retry_attempts):
            try: return func(*fargs, **fkwargs)
            except:
                tb = traceback.format_exc()
                if timeout is not None:
                    time.sleep(timeout)
                print 'Catching exception %s. Attempting retry: '%(tb)

        raise
    return tryIt
```

The decorator module helps me to decorate my datawarhouse call functions. So I don't need to take care of connection dropping and various connection based issues and allow me to reset the connection and try again after some timeout . I decorate all my functions which do data-warehouse reads with this method, so I get retry for free .

I have the following methods .

```
def process_generator(data):
    #Process the generated data


def generator():
    data = data_warhouse_fetch_method()#This is the actual method which needs retry
    yield data

@test_retry(number_of_retry_attempts=2,timeout=1.0)
def data_warhouse_fetch_method():
    #Fetch the data from data-warehouse
    pass
```

I try to multi process my code using multiprocessing module like this.

```
try:
    pool = Pool(processes=2)
    result = pool.imap_unordered(process_generator,generator())
except Exception as exception:
    print 'Do some post processing stuff'
    tb = traceback.format_exc()
    print tb
```

Things are normal when everything is successful . Also things are normal when it fixes itself within the number of retries.  But once the number of reties exceeds i raise the exception in the test_retry method which is not getting caught in the main process . The process dies and the processes forked by main process are left as orphans . May be I am doing something wrong here . I am looking for some help to fix the following problem . Propagate the exception to parent process so that I can handle the exception and make my children die gracefully . Also I want to know how to inform the child processes to die gracefully.  Thanks in advance for the help .

**Edit :** Added more code to explain.

```
def test_retry(number_of_retry_attempts=1, **kwargs):
    timeout = kwargs.get('timeout', 2.0) # seconds
    @decorator.decorator
    def tryIt(func, *fargs, **fkwargs):
        for _ in xrange(number_of_retry_attempts):
            try: return func(*fargs, **fkwargs)
            except:
                tb = traceback.format_exc()
                if timeout is not None:
                    time.sleep(timeout)
                print 'Catching exception %s. Attempting retry: '%(tb)
        raise
    return tryIt

@test_retry(number_of_retry_attempts=2,timeout=1.0)
def bad_method():
    sample_list =[]
    return sample_list[0] #This will result in an exception


def process_generator(number):
    if isinstance(number,int):
        return number+1
    else:
        raise

def generator():
    for i in range(20):
        if i%10 == 0 :
         yield bad_method()
        else:
            yield i

try:
    pool = Pool(processes=2)
    result = pool.imap_unordered(process_generator,generator())
    pool.close()
    #pool.join()
    for r in result:
        print r
except Exception, e: #Hoping the generator will catch the exception. But not .
    print 'got exception: %r, terminating the pool' % (e,)
    pool.terminate()
    print 'pool is terminated'
finally:
    print 'joining pool processes'
    pool.join()
    print 'join complete'
print 'the end'
```

The actual problem grinds down to if the generator is throwing an exception , I am unable to catch the exception thrown by the generator in the except clause which is wrapped around  pool.imap_unordered() method . So after the exception is thrown the main process is stuck and the child process waits forever .Not sure what I am doing wrong here .

Comment: What does it look like when "the process dies". Any exception? Does it freeze? Have you tried returning `None` instead of an exception?

Comment: It does throw the original exception and the parent process dies leaving the child process forked as orphans .

Comment: What if you add `finally: pool.join()`

Comment: Same as before after adding finally:pool.join . The parent dies and leave the child process as orphan . The only other thing which is different is I have this following traceback .`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_exception.py", line 48, in <module>
    pool.join()
  File "/Users/senthilsrinivasan/.localpython/lib/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 456, in join
    assert self._state in (CLOSE, TERMINATE)`

Comment: Then you need to call `pool.close()` first. See [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15314189/python-multiprocessing-pool-hangs-at-join).

Comment: I tried that and updated my original question with more concrete example . The process which is responsible for consuming the generator throws an exception , but I could not catch that exception in the main process . So when the exception is thrown the process does not signal end of work to the child process which is stuck indefinitely . IF there is a any way to catch that original exception in the main process ?

Comment: I can not run the code:     @decorator.decorator
NameError: global name 'decorator' is not defined

Comment: decorator is a external python package available via easy_install .You can do a  easy_install decorator to install it . Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand the code that was shared here as I am not an expert. Also, the question is nearly an year old. But I had the same requirement as explained in the topic. And I managed to find a solution:

```
import multiprocessing
import time


def dummy(flag):
    try:
        if flag:
            print('Sleeping for 2 secs')
            time.sleep(2)  # So that it can be terminated
        else:
            raise Exception('Exception from ', flag) # To simulate termination
        return flag  # To check that the sleeping thread never returns this
    except Exception as e:
        print('Exception inside dummy', e)
        raise e
    finally:
        print('Entered finally', flag)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    args_list = [(1,), (0,)]
    # call dummy for each tuple inside args_list. 
    # Use error_callback to terminate the pool
    results = pool.starmap_async(dummy, args_list, 
                                error_callback=lambda e, mp_pool=pool: mp_pool.terminate())
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
    try:
        # Try to see the results.
        # If there was an exception in any process, results.get() throws exception
        for result in results.get():
            # Never executed cause of the exception
            print('Printing result ', result)  
    except Exception as e:
        print('Exception inside main', e)

    print('Reached the end')
```

This produces the following output:

```
Sleeping for 2 secs
Exception inside dummy ('Exception from ', 0)
Entered finally 0
Exception inside main ('Exception from ', 0)
Reached the end
```

This is pretty much the first time I am answering a question so I apologise in advance if I have violated any rules or made any mistakes.

I had tried to do the following without success:

1. Use apply_async. But that just hung the main process after the exception was thrown
2. Try killing the processes and children using the pid in error_callback
3. Use a multiprocessing.event to track exceptions and check the same in all processes after each step before proceeding. Not a good approach but that didn't work either: "Condition objects should only be shared between processes through inheritance"

I honestly wish it wasn't so hard to terminate all processes in same pool if one of the processes threw an exception.